# is there a difference between HttpPost AcceptPost and PostOnly attributes from mvc2 and mvccontrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

is there a difference between HttpPost from mvc2 and AcceptPost, PostOnly attributes from  mvccontrib ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AcceptPost was implemented as HttpPost in mvc 2, and was thus removed from MVCContrib.  The functionality is the same.

http://github.com/mvccontrib/MvcContrib/commit/e5549ae3418cd88456cc92bd012d7316e645d893